# java.lang.IllegalStateException gives no reference to my code

Tags: android, crash

Bellow error has been reported to me from several users. Myself I cannot reproduce the error. And I do not understand where the error occurs - there is no reference to my code in it. Any tips what could be the problem here ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you have `onClick` defined on any buttons in your xml layouts?

Comment: Make sure all of them have a matching `public void methodName(View v)`. Having a `View` as a parameter is essential.

Comment: Looks like a button is being pressed in a non UI thread. Find out which button the user reporting the error is pressing and investigate the code behind it.

Comment: @bclymer I think you were right. I found one `onClick` item in xml layout which I forgot to remove as I implemented `onClickListener` instead.

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer so that this question can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that for every `onClick` defined in your xml layouts, there is a matching `public void methodName(View v)` within the class that inflates the layout. The `View` parameter is essential.